# Looking for a convenient way to start and stop applications with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

For each of my projects, I have configured a docker development environment consisting of several containers. I often switch between projects. That requires stopping one set of containers and starting another. I currently do it like this:

```
$ cd project1
$ docker-compose stop
$ cd ../project2
$ docker-compose up -d
```

So I need to remember which application is currently running, `cd` into the directory where its `docker-compose.yml` is, stop it, then remember what other project I want to run, `cd` there and start it.

Is there a better way? Like a utility that remembers which multicontainer applications I have, can stop the currently running one and run another one without manual `cd`ing and `docker-compose`ing?

(By the way, what's the correct term for a set of containers hosting parts of a single application?)

Comment: Kubernetes uses "pod" to fit the whale theme, although a pod is a bit more specific than a set of containers. ECS calls them "tasks". Docker doesn't really have an official term, maybe a "composition"?

Comment: What is the problem with running another `docker-compose up -d` without stopping previous one?

Comment: @MateuszMoneta They may (and, in my case, always will) map to the same port on the host system.

Comment: I'd do it with a bash script in the parent directory. Also, it may be possible (and simpler) to stop all containers on your system using docker stop $(docker ps -q), or maybe writing a script that can stop all container names, to avoid having to try and figure out which project is running.
Unfortunately I don't know of a better way. The 4 commands you've listed are much easier than the same task would be without Docker!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope [docker-compose-ui](https://hub.docker.com/r/francescou/docker-compose-ui/) will help you in managing applications.

Comment: Looks like what I need, but I need to check it out before accepting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the real problem here is this:

> That requires stopping one set of containers and starting another.

You shouldn't need to stop one project to start another.

Instead of mapping to the same host ports I would not map any ports at all. Then use a script to lookup the IP of the container, and connect directly to that:

```
#!/bin/bash
cip=$(docker inspect -f '{{range $key, $value := .NetworkSettings.Networks}} {{ $value.IPAddress}} {{end}}' $1)
```

This will look up the container ip. Combine that with a command to open the url:

```
url=http://cip:8080/
xdg-open $url || open $url
```

All together this will let you run the application without having to map any host ports. When host ports don't exist, you don't have to stop other projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ruby proven a bit, you can use scaffolding for this.

A barebone example using thread ( to start different docker-compose session without one process and then stop them all together )

```
require 'docker-compose'

threads = []

project_paths = %w(/project/path1 /project/path2 /project/path3 /project/path)

project_paths.each do |path|
  threads.push Docker::Compose::Session.new(dir:compose_base_path1)
end

begin
  threads.each do |thread|
    thread.join
  end
rescue SystemExit, Interrupt
  threads.each do |thread|
    thread.kill
  end
rescue Exception => e
  handle_exception e
end
```

[source](https://gist.github.com/EugenMayer/b0f49c99d28e66f3e4179c967540faa2)

It uses

- [docker-compose gem](https://github.com/xeger/docker-compose)
- threads

Just set project_paths to the folders of your projects. And if you want to end them all, use CTRL+c

You can of course go beyond that, using a daemon and try to start / stop some of them giving "names" and such, but i guess as a starting point for scaffolding, that should be enaugh